# Is there any function in libcloud to upload an image using openstack?

Tags: image, upload, openstack, libcloud

I am using libcloud to retreive information from openstack.Is there any method to upload an image ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LIBCLOUD-523) has been solved, there is no code in libcloud for putting an image.

But if you're working with OpenStack only, you should probably ditch libcloud and go [Glance](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-glanceclient/) directly or [python-shade](http://docs.openstack.org/infra/shade/index.html).